# Format string to date and print the calculated difference with current time in AWK

Tags: shell, date, awk

Below is the sample file. (test.txt)

```
First    2015-05-21 11:03:19.000708
Second   2015-05-20 16:17:05.101111
Third    2015-05-21 11:03:30.000204
Forth    2015-05-21 11:03:23.000611
Fifth    2015-05-21 11:03:27.000519
Sixth    2015-05-21 11:03:23.000470
```

If current time is "Thu May 21 12:03:09 EDT 2015",
I would like to see the expected output to be something like following:

```
First    01:00:10
Second   23:43:39
Third    00:57:30
Forth    00:57:37
Fifth    00:57:33
Sixth    00:57:37
```

I am trying with below command. Can you please try to fix it..

```
cat test.txt |awk '{cmd="date -d \""$2" "$3"\""
curr=`date`
cmd | getline var1
curr | getline var2
lag=var2-var1
print $1, lag
close(cmd)}'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: example output for: date difference > 1 day ....

Comment: awk is not shell. curr=`date` is shell syntax to set a shell variable to the output of a shell command. What you want is `awk -v curr="$(date)" '...'` instead to set an awk variable to the output of a shell command before awk starts to execute. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk, using its built-in time functions:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { now = systime() } { t = $2 " " $3; gsub(/[-:]/, " ", t); t = mktime(t); dt = now - t; s = dt % 60; m = int(dt / 60 % 60); h = int(dt / 3600); print $1, h ":" m ":" s }' filename
```

This works as follows:

```
BEGIN {                    # in the beginning:
  now = systime()          # remember the current time (as seconds since Epoch)
}
{
  t = $2 " " $3            # construct time stamp from input line, in 
  gsub(/[-:]/, " ", t)     # a format that mktime understands

  t = mktime(t)            # convert to seconds since Epoch
  dt = now - t             # diff to now

  s = dt % 60              # isolate seconds,
  m = int(dt / 60 % 60)    # minutes,
  h = int(dt / 3600)       # hours

  print $1, h ":" m ":" s  # then print the lot.
}
```

One might consider using `strftime` to format the output, but that'll break because of DST and because days are only 24 hours long. It's better to do it manually.